# Gathering coin volumes - Is my code running asynchronously?

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm fairly new to programming in python, I've been programming for about half a year. I've decided to try to build a functional trading bot. While trying to code this bot, I stumbled upon the asyncio module. I would really like to understand the module better but it's hard finding any simple tutorials or documentation about asyncio.

For my script I'm gathering per coin the volume. This works perfectly, but it takes a really long time to gather all the volumes. I would like to ask if my script is running synchronously, and if so how do I fix this? I'm using an API wrapper to communicate with the Binance Exchange.

```
import binance
import asyncio
import time

s = time.time()
names = [name for name in binance.ticker_prices()] #Gathering all the coin names
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def get_volume(name):
    async def get_data():
        return binance.ticker_24hr(name) #Returns per coin a dict of the data of the last 24hr

    data = await get_data()

    return (name, data['volume'])

tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_volume(name)) for name in names]

results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

print('Total time:', time.time() - s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `binance.ticker_24hr` does not look like it's a coroutine, it is almost certainly blocking the event loop and therefore preventing `asyncio.gather` to do its job. As a quick fix, you can use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor) to run the blocking function in a separate thread:

```
async def get_volume(name):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, binance.ticker_24hr, name)
    return name, data['volume']
```

This will work just fine for a reasonable number of parallel tasks. The downside is that it uses threads, so it might not scale to a huge number of parallel requests (or it would require unnecessary waiting). The correct solution in the long run is to use a library that natively supports asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

Maarten firstly you are calling get_ticker for every symbol which means you're making many unnecessary requests. If you call it without a symbol value, you get all tickers in one request. This removes any loops or async as well if you aren't performing other tasks. It looks like the binance library you're using doesn't support this. You can use [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/) to do it

```
return client.get_ticker()
```

That said I've been testing an asyncio version of python-binance. It's currently in a feature branch now if you want to try it.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance@feature/asyncio
```

Include the asyncio version of the client and initialise the client

```
from binance.client_async import AsyncClient as Client
client = Client("<api_key>", "<api_secret>")
```

Then you can await the calls to get the ticker for a particular symbol

```
return await client.get_ticker(symbol=name)
```

Or for all symbol tickers don't pass the symbol parameter

```
return await client.get_ticker()
```

Hope that helps